# What is the best practice to consolidate multiple Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, performance

For CSS, I can use SASS to import one CSS file to another and produce only single CSS file. What is the similar method for Javascript files?

Comment: Most JS compressors can do that (in addition to making the JS more compact).

Comment: It may depend on your choice of server-side technology. ASP.NET for example makes use of [bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: What technology does your backend use?

Comment: Our backend use Django, but I was looking for a tool that can work independently without being tied to a certain framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) (which is a Google product).

You would probably want the [Closure Compiler Application](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) form of the product.

A sample workflow would probably look like:

1. Create a list of your JS files and paths
2. Run the command to compile and concatenate files (`java --jar compiler.js --js path_to_file1.js --js path_to_file2.js (etc.) compiled.js`)

Closure Compiler also has a related project, [Closure Stylesheets](https://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/), that does the same thing for stylesheets.

This approach, of course means that there's a pre-compilation step. Depending on your backend, there also exist libraries that do the compilation when the page is built. For example, for JSP, there's [Granule](https://code.google.com/p/granule/) a tag library that creates the compiled JS and CSS files at page build.

There's a third possibility: modularization. Since you gave the example of being able to import CSS files in SASS, an analogue for JavaScript is using a module library, using either the [CommonJS standard](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS), or (the one I prefer), the AMD (asynchronous module definition) pattern, which I have personally used with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). RequireJS also comes with a nice optimizing tool that will bundle up (minify, compress, concat etc) all the required files for your application

**UPDATE**

Since you mentioned that you are using Django in the comments (might be useful to update the question with this info too), see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062420/django-auto-minifying-css-js-files-before-release) helps too

---

Comment: Might help to explain why this was downvoted. My answer seemed pretty reasonable for the question being asked. Any feedback for improvement?

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take note of this for now. It seems that I can start by finding out more about existing JS preprocessors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`minify`](https://code.google.com/p/minify/) which allows you to minify and combine javascript files. It also works with CSS.

Comment: No, my bad. It is not a Google product.